# iscsiadm: cannot make connection to ...: Connection refused

Tags: virtualbox, iscsi

I'm struggling to get iscsiadm to connect from the iSCSI Initiator VM (using VirtualBox) to my iSCSI Target VM (also on VirtualBox).

E.g.

```
iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal <ip address> --discover
iscsiadm: cannot make connection to <ip address>: Connection refused
```

There is a Host-only adapter network set up and I can SSH between the two VMs.

I disabled `iptables` to check if it was a firewall problem but was still getting the same problem.

Fwiw, on the Target machine I have:

```
# tgtadm --mode target --op show
Target 1: iqn.2014-03.my.target.server:tgt1
    System information:
        Driver: iscsi
        State: ready
    I_T nexus information:
    LUN information:
        LUN: 0
            Type: controller
            SCSI ID: IET     00010000
            SCSI SN: beaf10
            Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: null
            Backing store path: None
            Backing store flags: 
        LUN: 1
            Type: disk
            SCSI ID: IET     00010001
            SCSI SN: beaf11
            Size: 55 MB, Block size: 512
            Online: Yes
            Removable media: No
            Prevent removal: No
            Readonly: No
            SWP: No
            Thin-provisioning: No
            Backing store type: rdwr
            Backing store path: /dev/vg_iscsi/lv_iscsi_1
            Backing store flags: 
    Account information:
    ACL information:
        ALL
```

Any suggestions what else I can try?

Comment: firewalld was active on target and initiator for me. Turning them off fixed it. Thanks for the iptables hint!

Answer (score 1):

Your client machine have another session logged into that target.

First you will have to logged out that target from your client, then discover using your new targetname.

```
       Logout(change parameter accordingly):

        iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2001-05.com.doe:test --portal 192.168.1.1:3260 --logout
```

If your client still does not discover, use 0.0.0.0 3260 as portal for this particular iqn in your server machine. This should work fine.

server:

```
 o- portals .................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  | |     o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ..................................................................... [OK]
```

This is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

me@here:~$ sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.22.240

```
iscsiadm: cannot make connection to 192.168.22.240: Connection refused
iscsiadm: cannot make connection to 192.168.22.240: Connection refused
iscsiadm: cannot make connection to 192.168.22.240: Connection refused
^Ciscsiadm: caught SIGINT, exiting...
```

me@here:~$ sudo iscsiadm -m discovery**db** -t st -p 192.168.22.240

```
# BEGIN RECORD 2.0-873
discovery.startup = manual
discovery.type = sendtargets
discovery.sendtargets.address = 192.168.22.240
discovery.sendtargets.port = 3260
discovery.sendtargets.auth.authmethod = None
discov...
```